# Bigquery - max occurrence in relative timeperiod

Tags: google-bigquery

in my example i need to find maximum occurrence of events in any 60 seconds of time series.

So if i want to find maximum occurrence on my theoretical simplified data sample attcahed, i would like to have result, that maximum occurrence in 60 seconds is 20 starting in time 00:00:00 and finishing in 00:00:58. My time series has million of rows, so i need to find maximum occurrence of ANY 60 seconds.

Do i need to use some kind of iterations like WHILE loop, or is there any smarter optimized way please? in T-SQL i solved that with loop, but performance is low at such big dataset

[Data sample:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Bdr.png)

Comment: Please add the data sample as text to make reproduction easier and include the expected output